# How to get Elementor Control Value in another Control

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am building a Widget for Elementor. It's a 'basic' widget where I need to grab the value of a control. Like, if I choose a select control a method will be called and will show another select control or something. Here is what I am doing:

```
protected function register_controls()
{
$this->start_controls_section(
 'new_section',
   [
    'label' => esc_html__('Settings', 'textdomain'),
     'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
   ]
 );
       // New Select settings
        $this->add_control( 
            'data_types',
            [
                'label' => esc_html__('Testimonial Type', 'textdomain'),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::SELECT,
                'options' => [
                    'static' => 'Static',
                    'dynamic' => 'Dynamic',
                ],
                'default' => 'static',
            ]
        );

// I want to get 'data_types' value here to call the *get_data_by_type($type)*

$this->end_controls_section();
}

public function get_data_by_type($type){
 // Something will be done with the data type.
}
```